# how to run nodejs app in vps with plesk enable

Tags: node.js, centos7, vps

Hi guys im newbie in vps... I've bought  an ovh not managed vps . I like to face problems... But I don't find any documents to these one. Is simple like I said I want to run a nodejs app in centos vps environment but I have enabled plesk.. and I saw in console running the app with the trace but I try to open website with the port and doesn't find anything.

http://vps406315.ovh.net

Thx for all guys

-----------------EDIT-------------------

I'm going to explain better,sorry for previous post.

There is no error, in my console all is ok. Like I said i have an CentOS VPS. Steps that I did:

- Connect with PUTTY
- Go to folder where is the NodeJS project.
- I set the port to 8080
- Write node index.js
- The app is running and writing the right trace.
- I use chrome to check the ip, and show me the default plesk page.
- I use wget to check it, and with only http://92.222.71.137/. I attach
  an screenshot
- I tried to use with the port 8080 with the chrome and wget in putty,
  and the response was the same.
- In the other hand if I use http://92.222.71.137:8080/login with putty
  download the right login.html, and the nodejs app write a trace
  indicate me that someone connect to that page. But if I access with
  chrome is not working.

Now I would like no know how to make access frome Chrome.

Thx 4 all and sorry for my newbie knowledge

[image]

Comment: Maybe the provider block the 8080 port, and in this case others as well. Try another one (8473 for example, or a very high port 12345 for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was easy... only i had to open a port to use with TCP, using

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8856 --syn -j ACCEPT –

Answer (score 0):

You should give some other details on the configuration or eventual errors you get (both on the browser and the VPS) and how you run the node app (behind a web server, for example)

If you are not running you node app behind a web server, are the node app listening on the correct interface ? 127.0.0.1 and 92.222.71.137 (your site external address) are not the same.

On your VPS you can try to call the node app from the VPS itself using `wget` or `cURL` and looking for what happen in the app  trace.

Comment: I edit my post to answer and explain better the problem.